# Docker build via proxy returned TLS handshake timeout

Tags: centos, docker, proxy

I did try build Docker container,
Internet resources access only via proxy.
I did set proxy connection for Docker.
[Did use method 2](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-configure-docker-to-use-proxy/)

After did check this command

```
[root@server01 docker]# systemctl show docker --property Environment
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=https://user1:password1@ourproxy:1001/
```

Did try build Docker conteiner and did retrun error

```
[root@server01 newapp]# docker build -f Dockerfile -t newapp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  40.45kB
Step 1/32 : FROM python:2.7
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

How solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a private registry, you need to place the certificate for that under  /etc/docker/certs.d/***registryname***/ca.crt

**registryname** will change accordingly

Also, please change your **MTU** size to 1300, this was also one thing I did to resolve the error. Registry one I believe you might have already done. 
Command for MTU change

`ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1300`